# Having problems using a custom cell instead the default cell

Tags: ios

I have a simple project here https://github.com/spikepoolie/tracker.git where a view with username and password "you can enter any values" there is no validation, after clicking on the LOGON button, I want to take me to the tableview, it does but it is not using the custom cell I created.

Could some one take a look on the project and let me know what I am missing

Thanks
Rodrigo

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellCustomLoadCell";
    CellCustomLoadCell *cell = (CellCustomLoadCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellCustomLoadCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (CellCustomLoadCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.loadNumber.text=@"rodrigo";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show us your cellForRow method where you instantiate your cell. We cannot guess just by looking at your whole project in Github.

Comment: Check my last comment, that made it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you ned in your table view controller is this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CellCustomLoadCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellCustomLoadCell"];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellCustomLoadCell";
    CellCustomLoadCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.loadNumber.text=@"rodrigo";
    return cell;
}
```

Registering the nib, outside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is the new way to use a nib based cell.

You also have a problem in the ViewController class, on how you get the table view controller on screen. You shouldn't just add its view as a subview of your view. You could use a push or do a modal presentation to move to the next controller, or just change the root view controller of the window, like this (this code is in your ViewController class, and I've commented out the line where you add the subview):

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    RodrigoTableViewController *test = [[RodrigoTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RodrigoTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    //[self.view addSubview:test.view];

    self.view.window.rootViewController = test;
}
```

Comment: hey guys, I've tried all the suggestions but it still not working. I've modified so many time that I must have broken something else because the custom cell never shows up. Please can somebody fix on the github so I can put this to work? I've trying to get this done for the last 2 days,

Comment: @RodrigoSchreiner, I took your code in github, and changed it to what I have above, and that made it work. Have you made other changes since you uploaded it to github?

Comment: I've done tons of changes with everybody's suggestions and added new views to try to make it work and I think that is when I got screwed. Can you put your changes on Github so I can get the whole project and see it working. I didn't change anything on GitHub.
Thanks

Comment: @RodrigoSchreiner, I've uploaded it to jumpshare. https://jumpshare.com/b/gE3bdtpb53LnAiGWQdgA

Comment: Hi rdelmar I just got the files and I get this error 
reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier drigoCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: @RodrigoSchreiner, really, are you sure you're using my file. I just downloaded it, and it worked fine. Does the table view controller code look like what I posted above?

Comment: sorry.. I will try again when I get home. Maybe I am overseen the files and not getting the right ones.